# Aggregate categorical values in a list according to time Python

Tags: python, group-by, aggregate, categorical-data

I would like to aggregate my values according to time intervals, but I have categorical ones and there are many functions for numerical ones. Here the code:

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset=['timestamp'], inplace=True)
data.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp)
data2 = data.set_index('timestamp').groupby('host').agg("event").resample('10s').ffill()
data2
```

The output is:

```
host        timestamp          
abc         2021-03-15 15:15:00         NaN
            2021-03-15 15:15:10    Accepted
            2021-03-15 15:15:20    Accepted
            2021-03-15 15:15:30         NaN
            2021-03-15 15:15:40         NaN
Name: event, dtype: object
```

But I would like it to be:

```
host        timestamp          
abc         2021-03-15 15:15:00    Accepted, Refused, Accepted
            2021-03-15 15:15:10    Accepted, Accepted
            2021-03-15 15:15:20    Accepted
            2021-03-15 15:15:30         NaN
            2021-03-15 15:15:40    Refused, Refused, Accepted
Name: event, dtype: object
```

Can anyone help me?

The sample data before groupin is a dataframe like this:

```
    timestamp   host    event
0   2021-03-15 15:15:01 x   Accepted
3   2021-03-15 15:15:01 x   Accepted
6   2021-03-15 15:15:01 x   Accepted
9   2021-03-15 15:15:01 x   Accepted
12  2021-03-15 15:15:01 x   Accepted
15  2021-03-15 15:15:01 f   Accepted
20  2021-03-15 15:15:31 x   Failed
23  2021-03-15 15:15:33 x   Failed
26  2021-03-15 15:15:35 x   Failed
29  2021-03-15 15:15:37 x   Failed
33  2021-03-15 15:15:39 x   Failed
```

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Would you show the sample data before groupby ? i.e. the layout of `data`

Comment: Could you replace your categorical values by numerical? Accepted = 1, Refused = 0, ... maybe this is faster than finding a solution for explicitely categorical values.

Comment: Hi @SeaBean, I've shared the dataset. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi @Raja, I would not like to perform any kind of computation, even if I would put them into numerical values, I would like to have a sequence of items as ordered by time